# Jquery in a table to make textarea readonly

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which I have text in one column and textarea in second. I want all the input boxes to be readonly except the first one. and when a respondent enters some value in first box, box next to it becomes editable and so on.
Basically I want respondent to answer sequentially. Below is my HTML but not sure how to do this using jquery. Please suggest on code.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Reason 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="textarea">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Reason 2
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="textarea">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Reason 3
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="textarea">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you try something yet ??

Comment: @Tyagi I am stuck on how to keep on first input as editable and rest as readonly. Once I reach there, probably I will be able to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, the `textarea` tag is wrong. It should be `<textarea>`. So change your code to:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Reason 1
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Reason 2
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Reason 3
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And you can use `.next()` to make the work, `onBlur` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").prop("disabled", true);
    $("textarea:first").prop("disabled", false);
    $("textarea").blur(function(){
       if ($(this).val().length >  0)
           $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find("textarea").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8o0p0d1c/

Comment: Thanks Praveen, also can't we combine first 2 lines of jquery in one like : $("textarea:not(first)").prop('disabled',true);

Comment: Yes, @Vaibhav Possible! :)

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/8o0p0d1c/1/ It is not `:not(first)` but `:not(:first)`. `:)`